# Editing source code of a C++/assembly debugger to include additional assembly information?

Tags: c++, debugging, assembly, x86, gdb

I would like to add some meta-data to the disassembly output of a debugger. To save myself writing a debugger, it seems better to try and edit the source file of an existing debugger.

Lets say I am going to output the latency for each assembly instruction, in the disassembly view.

Which debugger would be the best to edit the source code to achieve this? Or, are there any other alternative solutions?

Comment: You can script gdb. Not sure why you need this while debugging, though.

Comment: @Jester I want to see the additional information only for critical path code, which is easiest-seen whilst stepping-through the critical path.

Comment: @Jester I dont understand what you mean by script gdb/how it would help me?

Comment: You can script gdb, you don't need to mess with its source code. I guess you can write a script that processes the disassembly and inserts the latency info. I am not sure how feasible this is, but might be worth a look. Also if you have C++ source, you can ask the compiler for assembly listing (at least for your own code) and preprocess that adding latency information.

Comment: Was really hoping to step-through the code and see my additional data, so the compiler outputting an assembly file not ideal.

Comment: Well, you would see the additional data (ie. the assembly source annotated with the latency info), but not the C++ source.

Comment: IDA Pro may be worth a look too. (Though, not for it's source-code) Its highly scriptable.

Comment: Unfortunately [Intel's IACA](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-architecture-code-analyzer) is closed source, and doesn't do a perfect job.  It only operates on regions of code between start and stop markers, presumably because finding critical paths in the disassembly of an entire binary would be too slow / too hard.  But anyway, adding this sort of output to a disassembler might be easier to start with than adding it to a debugger, since a disassembler just has one job.  GNU `objdump` is open source, and so is Agner Fog's `objconv`.

Comment: @PeterCordes the data I wish to output is coming from look-up tables. There is nothing clever/smart/calculated- I just need to know where in the open source code I would have to output it.

Comment: @user997112: my point was that a disassembler has a simpler task, so it might be easier to find the right place in the source.  Also, then you don't have to decide whether to base your critical-path analysis on the window of instructions that's currently visible in the debugger, or stuff like that.)

Comment: I guess you have a table of which instructions are dependency-breaking on which CPUs, as well as latencies and throughputs, too.  i.e. `xor same,same` is dependency-breaking on everything, but `sub same,same` isn't on every CPU.  And of course `mov reg, src` is dep breaking.  `popcnt` / `lzcnt` / `tzcnt` suprisingly have a false dependency on their output register on Intel CPUs, but not AMD. Intel Haswell does dual bookkeeping for 8 / 16bit partial registers, so there's no extra merge uop if a later insn reads a reg that was partially written, but there's no false dep when reading the 8 or 16b

Comment: Anyway, the kind of tool you're trying to make sounds really great.  However, it's not going to be easy to get it right, because there are a lot of corner cases.  Also, I think I'd like to have it built in to a disassembler, rather than a debugger, if I had to choose one.

Answer (score 0):

OllyDbg has [a plug-in system](http://www.ollydbg.de/Help/i_Plugins.htm) that allows you to modify its behavior. It is probably the best fit for what you are trying to do.